# Azure App Service installed to C:\home\site\wwwroot - New Relic error

Tags: azure, newrelic

In Azure DevOps (dev.azure.com) we publish our asp.net application to an Azure App Service.

In the Console of Azure, it says that the site is; C:\home\site\wwwroot

When we try and install the New Relic Azure Site Extension it fails because it expects the site to be in D:\ so doesn't install the NewRelic folder in wwwroot

Why would Azure install the application into C: and not D: ?

Note: We run the site from a package: **WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE** = 1

[image]

Here's KUDU, it thinks the site is in C: too:

[image]